# Where can I place the code to populate the table

Tags: vb.net, webforms

I have a WebForms application. It has a table (Repeater control) with an editable field Quantity. Also it has a Search box and Add To Cart button. I am facing an issue which is probably trivial, and yet I don't know how to deal with it.

If I place the code that populates the table in the Page_Load() method, search functionality works, but when the user clicks the Add To Cart button, the input in Quantity field is overwritten. This does not happen if I place the code that populates the table in the Init() method, but in this case the Search functionality doesn't work, as the search field is of course empty at the Init() stage.

Where should I place the code?

Here is some code. This builds the table based on Search text:

```
    Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
...

        If Not IsNothing(Request.QueryString("group")) Then
            buildTable(CInt(Request.QueryString("cat")), CInt(Request.QueryString("group")), CurrentPage)
        Else
            buildTable(CInt(Request.QueryString("cat")), 0, CurrentPage)
        End If
    End If
...

Sub buildTable(ByVal itemCat As Integer, ByVal itemGroup As Integer, Optional ByVal pageNo As Integer = 1)
...
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearch.Text) Then
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SearchText", txtSearch.Text)
            End If
...
```

Comment: A hint: Look into the `IsPostBack` property. If you want more help, we're going to see some code...

Comment: @Heretic Monkey I tried If Not IsPostBack, but in this case on postback the Search doesn't rebuild the table, which it should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I can get the value from the Search textbox from Page_Init() using Request.Form:

```
Dim searchText As String = Request.Form(txtSearch.UniqueID)?.ToString()
```